# How to prevent a Java Client from using system Proxy?

Tags: java, proxy

This piece of code does use the proxy, reads a web page and returns it as string

```
    public String getPageFromProxy(String urlAdress) {

    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlAdress);
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(System.getProperty("http.proxyHost"), Integer.valueOf(System.getProperty("http.proxyPort"))));
        HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(proxy);
        String authString = System.getProperty("http.proxyUser") + ":" + System.getProperty("http.proxyPassword");
        authString = Text.getBase64Encoded(authString);
        uc.setRequestProperty("Proxy-Authorization", authString);
        uc.connect();
        InputStream in = url.openStream();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String read;
        while ((read = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(read);
        }

        br.close();
        return sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

As you can see I have tried a lot to make it really use the proxy with some given credentials. I have also overwritten the java.net.Authenticator as suggested on stackoverflow. However it turns out the Java Client does not provide any credentials. The code works only as the client takes the system ProxySettings from the User after the Proxy gave a 407 answer

That does show null

```
System.out.println("Proxy is system " + System.getProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies"));
```

How do you properly set the proxy in Java 7 to only use the given credentials?

Thanks for any hints on debugging this!

Answer (score 1):

You've gone through a lot of work to set up your proxied connection, and then you are ignoring it all and opening a brand new connection with:

```
InputStream in = url.openStream();
```

You probably want to open your input stream on your proxied connection:

```
InputStream in = uc.getInputStream();
```